# CruiseControl.net Windows server 2008 Images missing

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have an issue using cruisecontrol dashboard on a windows server 2008 IIS7 installation.
Even if I use an integrated mode with webserver configuration section, or a classic mode, the dashboard itself will be displayed but any static content, javascript files, images will be displayed.
I don't know if this is an issue or a configuration mistake, I followed the installation procedure, but nothing works about static files.
I've looked for a solution in the iis log file, and I saw the http 200 for each static file.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the developer tools for Chrome/Firefox/IE to look at the requests being made for those static items.

Maybe you have your ccnet website on a port but the site makes requests for static items on port 80 by default.

Maybe ccnet is in a subdirectory and the static requests go to the root?

Answer (score 0):

Check that IIS Static Content is enabled:
Go to

- Control Panel
- Program & Features
- Turn Windows features on or off (upper left)
- Internet Information Servies/World Wide Web Services/**Static Content**